# MVC Validation Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

How do you validate a class using Validation attributes when validating strongly typed view models.

Suppose you have a view model like so:

```
[PropertiesMustMatch("Admin.Password", "Admin.ConfirmPassword")]
public class AdminsEditViewModel
{
    public AdminsEditViewModel()
    {
        this.Admin = new Admin(); // this is an Admin class
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectAdminsInGroup { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectAdminsNotInGroup { get; set; }

    public Admin Admin { get; set; }
}
```

I get null exception when on this line of PropertiesMustMatchAttribute

```
object originalValue = properties.Find(OriginalProperty,  true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
```

since Password field is a property of Admin class and NOT AdminsEditViewModel. How do I make it so that it will go so many levels deep until it does find property of Admin in the ViewModel AdminsEditViewModel?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `PropertiesMustMatchAttribute` class to parse the property name and search deeply.

This attribute is not part of the framework; it's included in the default MVC template (in AccountModels.cs)
You can therefore modify it to suit your needs.

Specifically, you would call `name.Split('.')`, then loop through splitted names and get the property values.
It would look something like

```
object GetValue(object obj, string properties) {
    foreach(strong prop in properties)
        obj = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)
                            .Find(prop, ignoreCase: true)
                            .GetValue(obj);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: not sure how to do it. can you please provide more info on this. thanks

Comment: @Shane: Here you go. (untested)